# That makes just another thirty dollars I owe you

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Grey dug in his pocket and pull out the ten-dollar bill.
> “Here,” he said and handed the bill to Lucas. “***That makes*** just another thirty dollars I owe you, right?” Lucas took the bill as he bent low to look Grey in the eye. “That's right, but it's not too late to change your mind,” he said.

[Reference](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=NopeFdqj_P0C&pg=PA118&dq=here+%22that+makes+*+dollars+i+owe+you%22&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip_I3Zvub2AhU5kVYBHV-FA8kQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=here%20%22that%20makes%20*%20dollars%20i%20owe%20you%22&f=false)

---

The word "that" is used for referring to something that has already been mentioned.

I'm not sure what "***That***" refers to in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That** and **this** are used in dialogue to refer to a matter being discussed.

In this case, "that" refers **to the fact of giving Lucas some amount**  that is not the full amount.

You ask me for **100** dollars.
I **give you** **50** dollars.
Then, I say:
**That** is 50 dollars short of the what you asked for.

In other words, here "that" refers to the gesture of giving money to someone and commenting on it. The physical gesture in this case.

This is what is called deixis. A deictic expression.

[deixis](https://www.thoughtco.com/deictic-expression-deixis-1690428)

Comment: I'd also like to know what "***makes***" in the original post means in that context.

Comment: It makes or that makes refers to counting money here. If I count out 10 dollars in single dollar bills to you, when I reach the ten mark, I say: That makes ten. i.e. comes to ten.

Comment: I wonder if "That" in "That makes ten. i.e. comes to ten." refers to "counting out 10 dollars in single dollar bills to me".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss I have explained this and that well enough. You can take it or leave it. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is unspoken context here that both characters are aware of - that Grey owed Lucas $40 immediately prior to this particular scene. Grey is paying Lucas $10, so what he says to Lucas is equivalent to

> This $10 is deducted from the $40 I owe you, so now I owe you only $30, am I correct?